# How to rename an picture retrieved from gallery and save it with new name

Tags: android, file

I am getting image from gallery and after that I want to get the file name from filepath and rename it and save it again. Is this possible? If yes, how?,Itried below code but its not working

### code:

```
  File photo = new File(Utilities.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri, this));
  File renamed_File = new File("DeviceId" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
  photo.renameTo(renamed_File);
  System.out.println("Renamed file---->" + photo.getName());
```

Comment: You want it saved in the same location ?

Comment: yes same location can we rename that?

Comment: When two users send same downloaded images to server then server side those images names will duplicate,That's why i would like to rename with time in milliseconds

Comment: I am not understand ,Can you explain with code?

Comment: i am using volley